# Mobx : changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed (asynchronus handler)

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

we know all this problem, and know how to solve it.

But I have an stranger Error in this context where I could use a good hint:

```
this.getData(id)
            .then((response) => {
                        this.root.basic.selected.num = response.data.number; // number
                        this.root.basic.selected.date = response.data.date; // Date
                        this.root.basic.selected.text = response.data.text; // String. <- There is the error 
                }
            })
```

The `selected` Object is bound by the "makeAutoObserveable()" Nothing special here. But a lot of code to push it all here.

Why this error happens only on the .text setter not on the others?

Is this a possible known behavior?

I solved it with "runInAction()" but I would like to understand the reason.

Kind Regards
Gregor

Comment: So if you remove `text` assignment then there is no error, is that what you mean?

Comment: exactly. I did expect an error on each line or on none of them. But not only on the string line.

Comment: Quite weird. The new data is different from the current one? Maybe there is no error when data has same values

Comment: Maybe, ill gonna check this further. ... still open for hints. Otherwise Ill post an answere if I find the point.

Comment: Are you sure you are using other values at all? If you are not using them then there would be no warning by default, because no observers are observing this values and it does not matter if there is an action or not.

Comment: Thats a good point. I didnt check if values are null or equal. Would explain a lot

Comment: No, not null or equal. I've already checked and this won't matter. You need to check that you are using this values in your observers, that something actually calling them.